# FTP upload vb script : files are not overwriting

Tags: ftp, vbscript

I am passing value as 16 but its not working for me, my files are not overwriting and even getting popup also, Is there any work around ? I checked with as 20 value also but not working.

```
Const copyType = 16

strFolderPath = "D:\sample"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(strFolderPath)

strFTP = "ftp://" & strFTPUser & ":" & strFTPPass & "@" & strFTPHost & strFTPDir

Set objFTP = objShell.NameSpace(strFTP)

objFTP.CopyHere objFolder.Items,copyType
```

Answer (score 0):

The important questions are not for hobby programmers. A forum can help you to find out, what a userform etc. is.